# CGRectIntersects ball collision issue (it 'eats' the ball)

Tags: ios, objective-c

My issue here is that when I use the CGRectIntersects (rect,rect) that the ball i'm using ends up inside of the paddle, being eternally stuck. This happens often with the computer paddles, and rarely with the player paddles.

The objective of all this is to have the paddle reverse the ball direction over the "Y-Axis" or the "X-Axis" depending on which hit box it hits on which paddle.

I will post all the methods I have tried with fixing this (none had a particularly good result).
The first method I tried to fix this (uncommented parts) is using 'hit boxes'. I put three empty UIImageViews onto each paddle to represent the Top/Bottom, and the Right/Left. The 'hit boxes' are really just CGRectIntersects on the different UIImageViews. This has been the most effective so far.

I have also tried to use "invisible barriers" to reflect the ball. These are the commented out parts under "// Invisible Barrier Method". These worked okay, the ball got stuck sometimes, but I couldn't get it to hit the sides / corner of the paddle correctly.

The original was the CGRectIntersects method. This would take the ball and reflect it fine (until at high-speeds) but it would also reflect the ball if it hit the back ends of the paddle. Which is something that I don't want it to do.

Since I can't post images, i'll describe the game view. You have four corner blocks that deflect the ball (one per corner). There are four paddles, two player paddles and two computer paddles. the computer paddles take the top and left sides of the screen, while the player paddles take the bottom and right of the screen. Each paddle is a rectangle that is 66x20 (horizontal paddles) and 20x66 (vertical paddles). The ball is 24x24 and the corners are each 30x30.

Game.m

```
-(void) Collision {

/*  if (ball.center.x - 12 >= Player.center.x - 35 && ball.center.x + 12 <= 
Player.center.x + 35 && ball.center.y + 12 <= Player.center.y - 10 && ball.center.y + 12 
>= Player.center.y - 15)
{
    y = -y;
}   */

// Player Paddle
// Invisible Barrier Method
/*
if (ball.center.x + 12 <= Player.center.x + 35 && ball.center.x - 12 >= 
Player.center.x - 35 && ball.center.y +12 >= Player.center.y - 10 && ball.center.y + 12   
<= Player.center.y - 3)
{
    y = -y;
}
*/


if (CGRectIntersectsRect(ball.frame,PlayerLeft.frame))
{
    x = -x;
}

if (CGRectIntersectsRect(ball.frame, PlayerRight.frame))
{
    x = -x;
}

if (CGRectIntersectsRect(ball.frame, PlayerTop.frame))
{
    y = -y;
}  
// Player Vert paddle
// Invisible Barrier Method
/*
if (ball.center.y -12 <= PlayerVert.center.y + 33 && ball.center.y +12 >= 
PlayerVert.center.y - 33 && ball.center.x + 12 >= PlayerVert.center.x -10 && 
ball.center.x +12 <= PlayerVert.center.x -3)
{
    x = -x;
}
 */
 //=============================

if (CGRectIntersectsRect(ball.frame, PlayerVertBottom.frame))
{
    y = -y;
}
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(ball.frame, PlayerVertTop.frame))
{
    y = -y;
}
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(ball.frame, PlayerVertLeft.frame))
{
    x = -x;
}


// Computer Paddle
// Invisible barrier method
/*
if (ball.center.x - 12 >= Computer.center.x - 33 && ball.center.x +12 <= 
Computer.center.x + 33 && ball.center.y - 12 <= Computer.center.y +10 && 
ball.center.y   >= Computer.center.y - 10)
{
    y = -y;
}

if (ball.center.x + 12 >= Computer.center.x - 33 && ball.center.x + 12 <= 
Computer.center.x - 30 && ball.center.y - 12 <= 30)
{
    x = -x;
}

if (ball.center.x - 12 <= Computer.center.x + 33 && ball.center.x - 12 >= 
Computer.center.x + 30 && ball.center.y - 12 <= 30) {
    x = -x;
}
*/
// Hit box Method
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(ball.frame,ComputerBottom.frame))
{
    y = -y;
}
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(ball.frame,ComputerLeft.frame))
{
    x = -x;
}
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(ball.frame, ComputerRight.frame))
{
    x = -x;
} 


// Computer Vert Paddle
// Invisible barrier method
/*
if (ball.center.x - 12 <= ComputerVert.center.x + 10 && ball.center.x - 12 >= 
ComputerVert.center.x - 10 && ball.center.y - 12 <= ComputerVert.center.y + 33 && 
ball.center.y + 12>= ComputerVert.center.y - 33) {
    x = -x;
}
*/
// Hit boxes method
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(ball.frame, ComputerVertBottom.frame))
{
    y = -y;
}
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(ball.frame, ComputerVertTop.frame))
{
    y = -y;
}
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(ball.frame, ComputerVertRight.frame))
{
    x = -x;
} 


// Bottom right corner (image)
// Top Side
if (ball.center.x >= 278 && ball.center.x <= 308  && ball.center.y >= 327 &&   
ball.center.y <= 335) {
    y = -y;
}

// Left Side
if (ball.center.x >= 278 && ball.center.y >= 328 && ball.center.y <= 369) {
    x = -x;
}

// Bottom left corner (image)
// Top Side
if (ball.center.x >= 12 && ball.center.x <= 42 && ball.center.y >= 327 && 
ball.center.y <=329) {

    y = -y;
}

// Right Side
if (ball.center.x <= 42 && ball.center.y >=328 && ball.center.y <= 358) {

    x = -x;
}

// Top right corner (image)
// Bottom Side
if (ball.center.x <= 319 && ball.center.x >= 289 && ball.center.y <= 42 && 
ball.center.y >= 32) {

    y = -y;
}

// Left Side
if (ball.center.x >= 278 && ball.center.y >= 11 && ball.center.y <= 41) {

    x = -x;
}

// Top Left Corner (Image)
// Bottom Side
if (ball.center.x >= 12 && ball.center.x <= 42 && ball.center.y <= 43 && 
ball.center.y >= 41) {

    y = -y;
}

// Right Side
if (ball.center.x <= 42 && ball.center.y <= 41 && ball.center.y >= 11) {

    x = -x;
}
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

if i'm visualizing this correctly you want to only deflect if it hits the "front" of the paddle? conceptually i would try using a zero size rect and add other rects around it so you can be more granular as to which "side" of the rect is hit. or you could also create another rect that is an "outline" of the section of the paddle you want "active". something like this maybe...

```
CGRect paddleRect = CGRectMake(Computer---.frame.origin.x, Computer---.frame.origin.y, Computer---.frame.size.width, Computer---.frame.size.height / 2);
```

that would give you a rect that borders exactly half of the original rect.